# How do you translate old SQL database data to a new table layout?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design, data-binding

We have and old database with a poorly thought out table structure, virtually no relationships setup and no naming schemes. I've created a new database with a clean relational data structure that implements proper design practices.

I'm looking for advice on different methods to migrate the old data over to the new format. This will require a lot of data re-shaping which won't be fun. The data is heavily accessed and the challenge will be to keep both databases in sync for all relevant data (accounts, important services etc).

I thought triggers might be the way to go here - but maybe there is a different method that I am unaware of (maybe MS Sync Framework, or a code-level data adapter which will be more work because there is so much data access code spread all over the place, classic ASP and .Net over dozens of projects). The database in question is SQL Server 2005, running in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode.

Comment: Personally i would write a program to move the data, and test it until the result is as you want. Then when you want to go live you can run it during downtime and the job is done. You really need to test thoroughly though especially if changing the structure heavily and you are adding referencial integrity rules in the new database. If the database was written badly, theres a good chance the software running on it was aswell.

Comment: yes the software was written poorly as well. It's one of those situations where a company develops things over long periods of time with many different developers. Ended up with a mess. Migrating the data with a migration app all at once isn't really an option, since the old system will maintain some of the old products while the new products move to the new system.

Comment: one idea I had was to create an 'adapter' schema in the new database, which would contain tables that relate the old primary keys to the new primary keys and allow for keeping data sync'd between the two. The new system wouldn't update the old system, but changes to the old system would always propagate to the new one entirely using triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go is to write a stored procedure in the new database, which will actually pull your **delta** changes (only the modifications that were done from the last run to the instant the stored proc is run), and put this stored procedure in the sql agent job.

Configure the sql agent job to run for every 15 minutes and let the data sync in.

**disadvantages of using triggers in this scenario**

triggers will reduce the performance, as the sql server will execute the trigger code as well along with the update/ insert /delete statements and includes these as part of the execution at every time, i.e. if your trigger code takes 2 seconds to execute and the update statement with no trigger takes 2 seconds to execute, then the update time will be increased to 4 seconds with trigger in place. So employing triggers in this case might result in huge performance bottle neck.

Comment: I hear you.. any recommendations on how to determine the delta? Performance will definitely be affected by using the triggers, I'm guessing row versioning could be utilized here to determine which rows have changed. However, performance may also be hit here as I will need to potentially compare millions of rows for version changes.

Comment: Can you tell us what sql server version (2005,2008...) and the edition (Developer / Standard / Enterprise.... ) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same situation at my work, and I'm currently writing an application to do the migration.  The original database has no established relationships, so it's really like a set of disconnected spreadsheets.  By building my own application, I'm able to migrate the data using newly-established foreign keys, and assign data-specific defaults in place of nulls.